# Botframework v4: string "No" in confirmPrompt is being recognized as cancel in luis.ai

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Hello when i prompt the user with a confirm prompt or a yes or no prompt. Luis is detecting "no" as cancel intent which cancel my whole dialog. And then i deleted "no" from the cancel intent but now "no is being detected by luis as a greeting intent. There is not even a "no" word from the greeting intent. As much as possible i do not want to disable luis because a user can cancel anytime. How can i fix this? thanks!

Here is the code.

```
       public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dc = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        var activity = turnContext.Activity;

        var userstate = await _basicAccessors.BasicUserStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new BasicUserState(), cancellationToken);
        var state = await _basicAccessors.BasicStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new BasicState(), cancellationToken);

        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            turnContext.TurnState.Add("BasicAccessors", _basicAccessors);
            string text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text) ? string.Empty : turnContext.Activity.Text.ToLower();

            var luisResults = await _services.LuisServices[LuisConfiguration].RecognizeAsync(dc.Context, cancellationToken);

            var topScoringIntent = luisResults?.GetTopScoringIntent();
            var topIntent = topScoringIntent.Value.intent;

            string userName = string.Empty;
            if (activity.From.Name != null)
            {
                userName = activity.From.Name;
            }
            userstate.Name = userName;

            await _basicAccessors.BasicUserStateAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, userstate);
            await _basicAccessors.BasicStateAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, state);

            var interrupted = await IsTurnInterruptedAsync(dc, topIntent);
            if (interrupted)
            {
                // Bypass the dialog.
                // Save state before the next turn.
                await _basicAccessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                await _basicAccessors.UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                return;
            }

            // Continue the current dialog
            var dialogResult = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();

            // if no one has responded,
            if (!dc.Context.Responded)
            {
                // examine results from active dialog
                switch (dialogResult.Status)
                {
                    case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
                        switch (topIntent)
                        {
                            case GreetingIntent:
                                await dc.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialogId);
                                break;

                            case "loan calculator":
                            case "loan calc":
                                await dc.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialogId);
                                break;

                            case NoneIntent:
                            default:

                                await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("I didn't understand what you just said to me.");
                                break;
                        }

                        break;

                    case DialogTurnStatus.Waiting:
                        // The active dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing.
                        break;

                    case DialogTurnStatus.Complete:
                        await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                        break;

                    default:
                        await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            if (activity.MembersAdded != null)
            {
                // Iterate over all new members added to the conversation.
                foreach (var member in activity.MembersAdded)
                {
                    // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
                    // To learn more about Adaptive Cards, see https://aka.ms/msbot-adaptivecards for more details.
                    if (member.Id != activity.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        await _basicAccessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await _basicAccessors.UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }

 private async Task<bool> IsTurnInterruptedAsync(DialogContext dc, string topIntent)
    {
        // See if there are any conversation interrupts we need to handle.
        if (topIntent.Equals(CancelIntent))
        {
            if (dc.ActiveDialog != null)
            {
                await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
                await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Ok. I've canceled our last activity.");
            }
            else
            {
                await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("I don't have anything to cancel.");
            }

            return true;        // Handled the interrupt.
        }

        if (topIntent.Equals(HelpIntent))
        {
            await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Let me try to provide some help.");
            await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("I understand greetings, being asked for help, or being asked to cancel what I am doing.");
            if (dc.ActiveDialog != null)
            {
                await dc.RepromptDialogAsync();
            }

            return true;        // Handled the interrupt.
        }
```

Comment: Is there a No intent?

Comment: There is not a no intent. only greetings,cancel,help and none intent.

Comment: Might need to create a No intent then. Somehow you need to make LUIS understand that No is different from cancel

Comment: But luis has a cost. Creating a no intent might make it more often to do a luis call resulting to more cost?

Comment: Can't understand how it will result in more cost or more calls when you create one more intent. Is there another intent you think that utterance No can be mapped to?

Comment: Did you mean to include only part of your `IsTurnInterruptedAsync` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like something of a design dilemma. My recommendation is to rearrange your bot's priorities so that LUIS is invoked *only* if your dialog hasn't been properly responded to. This could be accomplished by moving `IsTurnInterruptedAsync` from `OnTurnAsync` to a validator method. The validator method can be passed as an argument to your prompt's constructor:

```
_dialogs.Add(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRMPROMPT, ValidateAsync));
```

You'll want to make sure your top intent can be accessed from anywhere in case your prompt is in a different class. You can do this by adding the top intent to your turn state, which is state that only lasts for the scope of a single turn. Include this code in `OnTurnAsync`:

```
var topScoringIntent = luisResults?.GetTopScoringIntent();
var topIntent = topScoringIntent.Value.intent;

// Include this:
turnContext.TurnState.Add("topIntent", topIntent);
```

Your `ValidateAsync` method can look like this:

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(PromptValidatorContext<bool> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (promptContext.Recognized.Succeeded)
    {
        return true;
    }

    await IsTurnInterruptedAsync(promptContext.Context);

    return false;
}
```

Since `IsTurnInterruptedAsync` might be in a different class now, it will need to access the top intent through your turn state. If `_dialogs` is out of scope, you could add that to your turn state as well, or just make it a public/static property.

```
private async Task<bool> IsTurnInterruptedAsync(ITurnContext turnContext)
{
    var dc = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);
    var topIntent = turnContext.TurnState.Get<string>("topIntent");

    // See if there are any conversation interrupts we need to handle.
    if (topIntent.Equals(CancelIntent))
    {
        // . . .
```

This way, an interruption would only happen if the utterance isn't valid for the dialog.

You might want to allow interruptions even when an utterance is valid for the dialog. Anything is valid for a text prompt, of course, but you still might not want to allow a user to type "What do I do?" as their name. If you want to send the utterance to LUIS first for certain types of dialogs and send the utterance to the dialog first for other types of dialogs, you can check the type of the dialog that's on top of the stack like this:

```
var activeDialog = _dialogs.Find(dc.ActiveDialog.Id);
if (activeDialog is ConfirmPrompt || activeDialog is ChoicePrompt)
```

Comment: Thank you sir i will try this as soon as i get home. Thank you.

Comment: Sir can you explain the "turnContext.TurnState.Add("topIntent", topIntent) and "var topIntent = turnContext.TurnState.Get<string>("topIntent")" and also turncontext, waterfall stepcontext, prompt context and turnstate? I want to understand them more if its okay.

Comment: And sir what if the prompt is in another class dialog. How can i call those codes you add up?

Comment: Sir how about this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885861/stackoverflow-exception-in-a-simple-dialog-in-botframework-v4

Comment: It looks like it's being taken care of

Comment: I did not understand his explation so much though

Comment: You have two answers now and you accepted one of them

Comment: Sir @kyle can i ask about webview on messenger? My understanding is it just normal web page viewed on messenger with your bot thru a link the bot gave. But when i see tutorials on internet the steps are very complicated. I am giving a link now thru my bot and being displayed on messenger so i thought i can already do webview.

Comment: Do some research on your own and if you get stuck for more than two hours go ahead and ask a new question

Comment: Okay sir but my problem now is new luis subscription. I tried everything. Here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941992/question-about-changing-to-a-new-luis-key-with-botframework-v4

Comment: It looks like that question is being taken care of as well

Comment: I can't make it work until now sir. I did everything i think I'm still missing one step.

Comment: The LUIS sir. It says "Operation returned invalid status code Forbidden."

Comment: "Forbidden" means you should check your app ID, app password, LUIS keys, etc. That has nothing to do with this question and you should ask a new question about it if you still need help.