# Stackoverflow Exception in a simple dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, stack-overflow

Hello i am getting an Stackoverflow Exception in this two dialog. `Dialog A` is being called from a main dialog class. Dialog A have a choice to go to `Dialog A child` and `Dialog A child` has a choice to go back to `Dialog A`. But it is getting a Stackoverflow Exception. When i remove one from the other: Example removing `Dialog A child` from `Dialog A` or removing `Dialog A` from `Dialog A child`, the exception error disappears. In short it throw a Stackoverflow Exception when both dialog can call each other.

I know i can just `EndDialogAsync` in this specific scenario to go back to `Dialog A` but my real dialog flow is not together like this
. How to fix this?

Dialog A code:

```
 public class DialogA : ComponentDialog
{
    private const string InitialId = "dialogA";
    private const string ChoicePrompt = "choicePrompt";
    private const string DialogAchildId = "dialogA_childId";

    public DialogA(string dialogId)
        : base(dialogId)
    {
        InitialDialogId = InitialId;

        WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
         {
            FirstStepAsync,
            SecondStepAsync,
            ThirdStepAsync,
         };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(ChoicePrompt));
        AddDialog(new DialogA_child(DialogAchildId));

    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
            ChoicePrompt,
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Here are your choices:"),
                Choices = new List<Choice>{new Choice { Value = "Open Dialog A_Child", }, new Choice { Value = "Open Dialog B_Child" }, },
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please choose one of the options."),
            });
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value.ToLower();

        if (response == "open dialog a_child")
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogAchildId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ThirdStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    }
```

Dialog A child code:

```
 public class DialogA_child : ComponentDialog
{
  private const string InitialId = "dialogAchild";
    private const string ChoicePrompt = "choicePrompt";
    private const string DialogAId = "dialogAId";

    public DialogA_child(string dialogId)
        : base(dialogId)
    {
        InitialDialogId = InitialId;

        WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
         {
            FirstStepAsync,
            SecondStepAsync,
         };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));

    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
       ChoicePrompt,
       new PromptOptions
       {
           Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Here are your choices:"),
           Choices = new List<Choice> {new Choice { Value = "Open Dialog A" }, new Choice { Value = "Open Dialog B" }, },
           RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please choose one of the options."),
       });
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value.ToLower();

        if (response == "open dialog a")
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogAId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }
```

Main code that called dialog A:

```
   public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    private const string InitialId = "mainDialog";
    private const string ChoicePrompt = "choicePrompt";
    private const string DialogAId = "dialogAId";

    public MainDialog(string dialogId)
        : base(dialogId)
    {
        InitialDialogId = InitialId;

        WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
         {
            FirstStepAsync,
            SecondStepAsync,
            ThirdStepAsync,
         };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(ChoicePrompt));
        AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
            ChoicePrompt,
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Here are your choices:"),
                Choices = new List<Choice>{ new Choice { Value = "Open Dialog A" }, new Choice { Value = "Open Dialog B" }, },
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please choose one of the options."),
            });
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value.ToLower();

        if (response == "open dialog a")
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogAId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        if (response == "open dialog b")
        {
        }

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }

    private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ThirdStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please insert the class definition too? What is the base of DialogA_child and what is the base for DialogA?

Comment: You are recursively creating `DialogA_child` in `DialogA` constructor and `DialogA` in `DialogA_child`  constructor. This will not work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a "stack overflow" occur and how do you prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/how-does-a-stack-overflow-occur-and-how-do-you-prevent-it)

Comment: tl;dr you code is stuck in a permanent un-exit able loop

Comment: As  Paweł Łukasik noted perhaps you are willing to change your class modeling.

Comment: @Ucho i am willing to change my modeling for better can you give example sir? I am new in bot framework and c#.

Comment: @user10860402 You cannot do what Paweł Łukasik told you. You have to get rid of either of the those instantiations in constructors. Start with that.

Comment: How can i call them without creating them in the constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Visual Studio** you can check your `call stack` and you will know where is the exact problem in your `StackOverflowException`.

If DialogA is the base class of `DialogA_child` then in your `DialogA_child`'s constructor and your base class constructor will be calling themselfs recursively.

So your call stack should look like this:

1. `DialogA` constructor add new `DialogA_child`
2. `DialogA_child` calls base(so `DialogA constructor`)
3. `DialogA` constructor add new `DialogA_child`
4. `DialogA_child` calls base(so `DialogA constructor`)
5. ...

Comment: I am not yet familiar with base class sir i have updated the question with their class.

Comment: I kind of understand how can you prevent this sir if you want to separate your dialog? Because i want them separated to look cleaner.

Comment: If you do not have any reason to call `:base` (so base class' constructor), do not call it in your `DialogA_child`'s constructor. 
Also I just noticed, you add `DialogA_child` in your `DialogA`'s constructor and add `DialogA` in your `DialogA_child`'s constructor. This is a problem again.
Have one `DialogA_child` in your `DialogA` class **XOR** one `DialogA` in your `DialogA_child`'s class because this is another reason for a recursive call.

Comment: How to not call the base sir? i am getting an error that it is required.

Comment: How can i call another dialog without making an instance of them in the constructor? and how does one dialog become a base class of another dialog? in this 3 example dialog which is the base of which?

Comment: Why do you pasted MainDialog? MainDialog's constructor get called first, then DialogA and then call DialogA_child?
You didn't write appropriate description about your problem so I only can guess what is happening.
In definition  `class A : B{}` , `B` is the **base class** of `A`

Answer (score 2):

@koviroli's answer is 100% correct, so please accept his as the answer once you feel like you understand it. I'm adding this as an additional answer because it seems like you're struggling to understand things a little and comments limit me from providing good explanation.

#### Quick Explanation of Constructors

Since you're new to C#, I'll provide a quick explanation of constructors. `DialogA_child`'s constructor is this part:

```
public DialogA_child(string dialogId)
    : base(dialogId)
{
    InitialDialogId = InitialId;

    WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
     {
        FirstStepAsync,
        SecondStepAsync,
     };
    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
    AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));

}
```

Any time that you use `new DialogA_child("xyz")`, the constructor is called to "construct" `DialogA_child`. The `:base(dialogId)` makes it so that "xyz" gets sent to the constructor of `DialogA_child`'s base class, which is `ComponentDialog`. In `ComponentDialog`'s constructor, it sets the argument that gets passed in ("xyz", in this case) to the dialogId.

If you click on `ComponentDialog` in your code and press F12, it will take you to the definition of `ComponentDialog` and you can see this:

`public ComponentDialog(string dialogId);`.

#### Here's What's Wrong

In `DialogA_child`'s constructor, you have: `AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));`, which creates a **new** instance of `DialogA`. Then, in `DialogA`'s constructor, you have `AddDialog(new DialogA_child(DialogAchildId));`, which create **another** `DialogA_child`, and so on and so on.

Basically, `DialogA` and `DialogA_child` keep creating new instances of each other, causing the StackOverflow.

The easiest fix is to just remove `AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));`.

#### Additional Notes

Again, I know you're new to C#, so I'll help you out with a couple of other things.

`private const string ChoicePrompt = "choicePrompt";`

should probably be

`private const string ChoicePromptId = "choicePrompt";`

since `ChoicePrompt` is already defined as a type of prompt.

When defining your dialog constructors, it's easiest to use something like:

`public DialogA() : base(nameof(DialogA))`

This will automatically set the id of `DialogA` to "DialogA". It will help with two things:

1. Since dialogs have to use unique IDs, this will prevent you from accidentally calling the same dialog twice.
2. It's easier to keep track of and you don't have to pass in a name for it. For example, to call the dialog, you could now use `AddDialog(new DialogA());` instead of `AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));`.

#### Forcing a Dialog Loop

<strike>Currently, you cannot loop dialogs the way that you want to</strike> (See update below). You cannot:

1. Have `DialogA` call `DialogA_child`
2. Then have `DialogA_child` again call `DialogA`.

As you have seen, this creates a stack overflow.

Instead, you can call it indirectly.

Instead of having `DialogA_child` call `DialogA`, do something like:

1. Have `DialogA_child`'s choice prompt with an option of "Restart Dialog A" (or something unique).
2. In `OnTurnAsync` (in your bot's main Class file), check to see if the user responded with "Restart Dialog A". If so, clear all dialogs (or just replace) and then begin `DialogA` again.

Code:

`DialogA_child`:

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
    choicePrompt,
    new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Here are your choices:"),
        Choices = new List<Choice> { new Choice { Value = "Restart Dialog A" }, new Choice { Value = "Open Dialog B" }, },
        RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please choose one of the options."),
    });
}
```

`<myBot>.cs`:

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var activity = turnContext.Activity;

    var dc = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);

    if (activity.Text == "Restart Dialog A")
    {
        await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DialogA));
    }
```

## Update

BotBuilder SDK V4.3 will release soon that allows any child or sibling dialog to call any dialog defined by the parent. See [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/735). I *believe* you can have a child dialog call a parent, as OP requested, but it's still new and I haven't tested.

Comment: First thank you Mr.Richardson! I removed "AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId))" and I changed Dialog A`s constructor to this "public DialogA() : base(nameof(DialogA))" and added "AddDialog(new DialogA())" to DialogA_child. How can i begin DialogA now in DialogA_child?

Comment: See new edit, "Forcing a Dialog Loop". It's ugly and I don't really recommend it, but if you really want your dialogs to flow this way, this is how to do so.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for teaching that options but i kinda see now it is bad coding and im thinking to remodel my flow so that i will just `EndDialogAsync` child A to go back to dialogA. Thank you Mr.Richardson!

Comment: May i ask Mr.RIchardson what happens when you don't end your dialogs? And they stacked so many times?

Comment: @user10860402 Dialogs are supposed to end automatically when you reach the end of the last step, but it's good practice to end them manually. If you don't and they don't close themselves, your user might not use the dialog flow you intended.

Comment: @user10860402 I added an update to the end of my answer that you may find interesting. New update to the BotBuilder SDK.

Comment: Sir richard i already updated my SDK to 4.3 how can i use this new addition now that can call main dialog from its child dialog?

Comment: this is the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449059/botframework-v4-call-parent-dialog-from-child-dialog-without-stackoverflow-exce

Comment: @user10860402 Please don't link me to your questions. So long as you use the `botframework` tag, somebody on my team (often me) will get to them.