# Botframework v4: Call parent dialog from child dialog without stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, botframework

According to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/735) i think it is possible now to call the parent dialog from a child dialog. Before i can't do that because it will cause a Stack overflow exception. I've already updated to SDK 4.3 does anyone know how to implement this changes?

Main dialog calls dialog A.

```
WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
     {
        FirstStepAsync,
        SecondStepAsync,
        ThirdStepAsync,
     };
    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
    AddDialog(new DialogA(DialogAId));

  return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogAId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Dialog A calls Dialog Achild

```
    WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
     {
        FirstStepAsync,
        SecondStepAsync,
        ThirdStepAsync,
     };
    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
    AddDialog(new DialogAchild(DialogAchildId));

   return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogAchildId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Dialog Achild calls MainDialog, but this will produce a Stack overflow exception.

```
WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
     {
        FirstStepAsync,
        SecondStepAsync,
        ThirdStepAsync,
     };
    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialId, waterfallSteps));
    AddDialog(new MainDialog(MainDialogId));

  return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialogId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're adding the Dialogs in the constructor of your dialog, then you're producing an infinite loop ultimately resulting in the stack overflow you're describing.

```
MainDialog --> DialogA --> DialogAchild --> MainDialog --> infinite loop
```

The PR you're mentioning refers to a slightly different problem.

One way to work around this is to remove the AddDialog method causing the final loop from the constructor. Instead, move the call to a method like AddDialogA() and call it only if needed.

Based on your scenario, you could build a base dialog offering this kind of functionality.

Here is a sample of an `AuthenticatedDialog` offering you to add an `OnboardingDialog` when necessary. Note that the Onboarding Dialog itself inherits from AuthenticatedDialog which would cause an infinite loop as well when you're not offloading the `AddDialog()` call.

Abstracting this in base dialogs is nice, because it gives you a little API you can use. Consider naming your stuff like AddComponentDialog or UseComponentDialog. This way you're expressing your intend quite good and a potential reader knows initally that you're using re-usable components.

**AuthenticatedDialog.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Bot.Dialogs.Authentication;
using Bot.Dialogs.Main;
using Bot.Dialogs.Onboarding;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bot.Dialogs.Shared
{
    public class AuthenticatedDialog : EnterpriseDialog
    {
        private BotStateAccessors _accessors;
        private BotServices _botServices;

        public AuthenticatedDialog(BotServices botServices, string dialogId, BotStateAccessors accessors) : base(botServices, dialogId)
        {
            _accessors = accessors;
            _botServices = botServices;

            AddDialog(new AuthenticationDialog("", accessors));
        }

        protected async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskForOnboardingAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, object stepResult = null)
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OnboardingDialog), stepResult, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected void AddOnboardingDialog()
        {
            AddDialog(new OnboardingDialog(_botServices,_accessors));
        }

    }
}
```

**DialogA.cs**

```
public class DialogA : AuthenticatedDialog
{

        public DialogA(BotServices botServices, BotStateAccessors accessors) : base(botServices, nameof(DialogA), accessors)
        {

            var preferencesDispatchSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                WaterfallStepA,
                WaterfallStepB
            };

            AddDialog(new FooDialog);
            AddOnboardingDialog();
        }
}
```