# Question about changing to a new LUIS key with Botframework v4

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I downloaded the C# template in Azure. It automatically created and setup a LUIS app but now LUIS hits 1000 calls and expires now. I created a new key using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription). I managed to assign a resource but now what? I'm still getting an error that the quota limit was reached.

I tried changing the name and authoring key in the bot file but always getting error that I can't read bot file.

I also notice that the authoring key in LUIS app is much shorter that in the bot config. Can someone help me? Thank you.

UPDATE: I tries  these.

1. Created new luis subscription plan in azure portal with S0 pricing.
2. Created new LUIS app in LUIS.ai, assign new resource with the newly created luis plan from azure portal.
3. Add the service via bot emulator. Still Forbidden error.
4. Bot config showing old subscription key so i click the end point url in LUIS.ai it has a subscription key so i copy that to the bot config. (i remove the encryption.) still Forbidden error.

After all these steps it is still saying "invalid status code `Forbidden`"

[image: this is the error]

Luis ai

[image]
and [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a few issues to tackle.

1) I'm guessing that your .bot file has encrypted values. One, because you are reporting an error reading the .bot file. Did you edit it directly as JSON? And, two, because of the length of the authoring key. When the values are encrypted they will not match the original. Editing should be done via the Bot Framework Emulator. You can also remove file encryption there allowing you to edit the file directly, if that is what you want.

2) There is no way to transfer a LUIS.ai account from one LUIS subscription to another. You  can, however, create a new LUIS subscription and export/import the app to the new subscription under a new LUIS.ai account.

To that end, the starter key that is generated is used primarily for authoring new apps and with the [LUIS programmatic authorizing APIs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f). You should create a new endpoint key (accessible via Manage => 'Keys and Endpoints' in your LUIS app) and use this to send queries to your app for testing. This endpoint key carries a monthly limit of 10,000 messages/month on the free tier.

You can read about LUIS model/key boundaries (i.e. threshold limits) in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries). You can also read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription#viewing-summary-usage) on how to view your summary usage for managing your endpoint quota.

Hope of help!

Here's a listing of the key limits for immediate reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will do these and get back later. also do you know what is the difference when publishing luis in staging and production?

Comment: It is related because i chosed the 'F0' pricing in my new luis subscription?

Comment: I updated my question with the steps i tried. I still cant make it to work

Comment: Sir could you teach me this part. " You should create a new endpoint key (accessible via Manage => 'Keys and Endpoints' in your LUIS app) and use this to send queries to your app for testing. This endpoint key carries a monthly limit of 10,000 messages/month on the free tier."

Comment: Hi @user10860402, Sorry for not responding. It was my weekend and I was away. Try publishing your bot in LUIS.ai and let me know the results. Be sure you are publishing to production and that you are using that key.